# Importance of parameters on a report

Tags: reports

Is it really important to display the parameters selected by a user on a report? What is the best way to display the parameters?

Comment: A mockup will go a long way to explain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displaying the parameters that are selected by a user is very important. This gives clarity on  information as to what is the input / criteria as per which the report is generated.

Report input parameters are to be shown separately in the top of a report followed by the report data. As a good practice, if the report runs into multiple pages, report input parameters can be repeated on every page as part of report header